# How can I start a jar service with arguments

Tags: java, linux, service, jar

I am having a spring boot JAR file, which I am creating a link using the ln command so that I can run it as a service. I am aware that we can pass parameters during run time of jar using -D.

ln -s /root/test/ROOT.jar /etc/init.d/test

I can start the service with service test start, but how do I pass arguments to the jar file which is going to be started?

java -jar -Dparameter1=value1 ROOT.jar works but how do I do the same with service?

Comment: How do you expect the jar file to be executed? Typically Linux don’t support this so you may need a script.

Comment: I am writing this code as a chef recipe. So service test start runs the jar. But I wish to pass arguments to the jar here which I was unable to find a way.